# Check if node.js server is online?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there a way to check if Node.js server is online from html/javascript? When connected I show the messages, but if server is down, nothing happens. Is there a way to do it?

Thanks,
Mika

---

Yes, thanks for the answers, I used 'error' event on socket object to detect server down or outages so I'm assuming that if error is reported, server is down or client has internet connection problems.

Comment: Send a request to the server and see what happens?

Comment: I guess I need to use timeout event, I'll try it out and see what happens.

Comment: I did it with on error event, not sure if there is a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I'm using socket.io.

When using socket.io you have to resquest the socketio.js file to the server and, when this file is loaded it declares the global variable io

If the server is off in the first time you request your file from the  tag, you will need to rewrite this tag

```
var reloadIO = function (){

    // if server is not, serveri.io.js will be not available so we need to redeclare de dom node
    $("script[src*='socket.io.js']","head").remove();

    var script=document.createElement('script');
    script.type='text/javascript';
    script.src=ioSrc+"?"+Math.floor(Math.random()*111);;
    $("head").append(script);
    // nullify
    script = null;

    return;
};
```

And if you want to check if its loaded :

```
var isIOLoaded = function(){
    return (typeof(io) != "undefined") ? true : false;
}
```

This way you can have a setInterval checking if io is declared and if it's not, call reloadIO.

Comment: yes, but if node.js and webserver hosting client files are two different ones?

Answer (score 0):

Tan's answer is correct, but status code errors do not always state that the server is "down".  A 404 status code is simply stating that a document missing -- which is an actual response from your server.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using jQuery, you can send a simple AJAX request and use `error` callback. The `error` callback will be called when your server return 4xx or 5xx status code. If everything is ok, `success` callback is called

Answer (score -1):

If you are making this call **from** the node server to check another server you can do something like this:

```
      var url = ""; // url here
      var results = {};
      var errorMessage = "";
      var statusMessage = "OK";
      var isServerOk = true;
      var errorMessage = "";

      try {
        var urlResponse = await fetch(url);
        statusMessage = urlResponse.status + " " + urlResponse.statusText;
      }
      catch(error) {
        statusMessage = error.toString();
        errorMessage = error.message;
        isServerOk = false;
      }

      if (isServerOk==false) {
        results.status = "Not ok";
        results.statusMessage = statusMessage;
        results.errorMessage = errorMessage;
      }
      else {
        results.status = "OK";
      }

      // on node js 
      // response.status(200).json(results);
```

If the domain or sub domain are not available and error occurs and the code steps into the catch block.

This may also work the same in the client since the client browser has the `fetch` api but has not been tested there.